# Is there any way to execute the copy constructor when two user defined copy constructors present?

Tags: c++, optimization, constructor

```
1= Class_Name( Class_Name& object_name )
2= Class_Name( const Class_Name& object_name )
```

If both of these copy constructors are defined by user, Then is there any way to execute no(2) copy constructor(Taking copy elision
 concept into consideration )?

Comment: For some reason, I keep expecting the quick answer "Yes, there is."

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer by clicking the chechmark next to it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question... copy constructor no (2) can be executed

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Class_Name
{
  public:
  int xx;

  // Copy Constructor No. 1
  Class_Name(Class_Name& objCopy)
  {
      cout << "Copy Constructor No. 1 called" << endl;
  }

  // Copy Constructor No. 2
  Class_Name(const Class_Name& objCopy)
  {
      cout << "Copy Constructor No. 2 called" << endl;        
  }

  Class_Name(int x) : xx(x) {}  /* conversion constructor */
};


int main()
{    
    Class_Name obj1 = 1; // obj1 is not const, 1 is passed "by value", since it's primitive type
    Class_Name objCopy1 = obj1; // obj1 is not const, other is not const, obj1 is passed by const reference

    const Class_Name obj2 = 2; // obj2 is const
    Class_Name objCopy2 = obj2;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Copy Constructor No. 1 called
>
> Copy Constructor No. 2 called

**Copy Elision**

```
Class_Name objCopy1 = Class_Name(obj1);
```

would be same as

```
Class_Name objCopy1 = obj1;
```

Comment: I don't see how the concept of 'copy elision' is related to this!

Comment: I was trying to assign a R_Value object, which was implicitly calling constructor, not copy constructor with const reference.But the above example is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

```
const Class_Name ob1;
Class_Name ob2 = ob1;
```

That will invoke 2nd version of copy constructor. That's because your ob1 is defined as a constant. I would suggest you reading wikipedia once, quite nicely explained. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor